# limit proof explanation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence (for $n \in \mathbb{N}$) such that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$. Show that there is some subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ with $\sum a_{n_k}$ converges.

I found a couple of proofs and was wondering if someone could explain a part of them:

Proof technique 1:

By definition of lim inf, $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$ implies that there is an $n_k$ s.t. $|a_{n_k}| < 1$. Arguing by contradiction, suppose $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$ and there is no $n$ s.t. $|a_n| < 1$. By definition, $1$ forms a lower bound for $a_n$. For all $n > N$, $1$ then forms a lower bound for $a_n$. Hence, $1 \leq \inf \{a_n: n > N\} \implies \lim_{N\to\infty}\inf \{a_n: n > N\} \geq 1 \implies \liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| \geq 1$. Contradiction.

Proof technique 2:

Notice that $\liminf$ is a subsequential limit. So $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$ implies that there is an $n_{k2} > n_{k1}$ s.t. $|a_{n_{k2}}| < \frac{1}{2^2}$. Arguing by contradiction, suppose $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$ and there is no $n > n_{k1}$ s.t. $|a_n| < \frac{1}{2^2}$. Then for $n > n_{k1}$, $\frac{1}{2^2}$ forms a lower bound for $a_n$. For all $N > n_{k1}$, $\frac{1}{2^2}$ then forms a lower bound for $a_n$, where $n > N$. We have that $\frac{1}{2^2} \leq \inf \{a_n: n>N\} \implies \lim_{N\to\infty}\inf \{a_n: n > N\} \geq \frac{1}{2^2}$. Contradiction.

After either proof above, we have a sequence $\{a_{n_k}\} < \frac{1}{k^2}$. With the comparison test, $\{a_{n_k}\}$ converges.

QED.

Where I'm confused in particular is: Where did those starting conclusions from $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$ come from? How do we know that there is an $n_k$ such that $|a_{n_k}| < 1$? How do we know that there is an $n_{k2} > n_{k1}$ such that $|a_{n_{k2}}| < \frac{1}{2^2}$?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just choose a subsequence such that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_{n_k} = 0$? This works because $\displaystyle \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. Then, by definition of convergence you can find some $n_{k_j} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert a_{n_{k_j}} \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2^j}$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_{n_{k_j}} \leq \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} = 1$. So $a_{n_{k_j}}$ is the desired subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asserting that a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of non-negative numbers is such that $\liminf_nx_n=0$ is the same thing as asserting that it has a subsequence whose limit it $0$. So, there is some $n_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $\left|a_{n_1}\right|<1$. And, again since some subsequence of $\bigl(|a_n|\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $0$, there is some $n_2$ such that $\left|a_{n_2}\right|<\frac12$ and we may assume, without loss of generality, that $n_2>n_1$. And so on.